# constexpr member functions that don't use this?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, constexpr

Please consider the following two C++14 programs:

Program 1:

```
struct S { constexpr int f() const { return 42; } };
S s;
int main() { constexpr int x = s.f(); return x; }
```

Program 2:

```
struct S { constexpr int f() const { return 42; } };
int g(S s) { constexpr int x = s.f(); return x; }
int main() { S s; return g(s); }
```

Are neither, either or both of these programs ill-formed?

Why/why not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both programs are well-formed. The C++14 standard requires that `s.f()` be a constant expression because it is being used to initialize a `constexpr` variable, and in fact it is a core constant expression because there's no reason for it not to be.  The reasons that an expression might not be a core constant expression are listed in section 5.19 p2.  In particular, it states that the **evaluation** of the expression would have to do one of several things, none of which are done in your examples.

This may be surprising since, in some contexts, passing a non-constant expression to a `constexpr` function can cause the result to be a non-constant expression even if the argument isn't used. For example:

```
constexpr int f(int) { return 42; }

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    constexpr auto y = f(x); // ill-formed
}
```

However, the reason this is ill-formed is because of the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of a non-constant expression, which is one of the things that the **evaluation** of the expression is not allowed to do.  An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion doesn't occur in the case of calling `s.f()`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find a compelling passage or example in the standard that directly addresses the issue of calling a constexpr member function on a non-constexpr instance, but here are some that may be of help (from draft N4140):

`[C++14: 7.1.5/5]`:

> For a non-template, non-defaulted `constexpr` function or a non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting
>   `constexpr` constructor, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor
>   could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no
>   diagnostic required.

```
constexpr int f(bool b)
    { return b ? throw 0 : 0; }       // OK
constexpr int f() { return f(true); } // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
```

From this I take that the program is not outright ill-formed just because a constexpr function has a possible non-constexpr path.

`[C++14: 5.19]`:

```
int x; // not constant
struct A {
    constexpr A(bool b) : m(b?42:x) { }
    int m;
};
constexpr int v = A(true).m; // OK: constructor call initializes
                             // m with the value 42
constexpr int w = A(false).m; // error: initializer for m is
                              // x, which is non-constant
```

This is somewhat closer to your example programs, here a constexpr constructor may reference a non-constexpr variable depending on the value of the argument, but there is no error if this path is not actually taken.

So I don't *think* either program you presented should be ill-formed, but I cannot offer convincing proof :)

Answer (score -4):

This sounds like a quiz question, and not presented by a student, but the professor testing the public on stackoverflow, but let's see...

Let's start with the One Definition Rule. It's clear neither version violates that, so they both pass that part.

Then, to syntax. Neither have syntax failures, they'll both compile without issue if you don't mind the potential blend of a syntax and semantic issue.

First, the simpler semantic issue. This isn't a syntax problem, but `f()`, in both versions, is the member of a struct, and the function clearly makes no change to the owning struct, it's returning a constant. Although the function is declared constexpr, it is not declared as const, which means if there were some reason to call this as a runtime function, it would generate an error if that attempt were made on a const S. That affects both versions.

Now, the potentially ambiguous `return g(S());` Clearly the outer g is a function call, but S may not be so clear as it would be if written `return g(S{});` With {} initializing S, there would be no ambiguity in the future should `struct S` be expanded with an operator() (the struct nearly resembles a functor already). The constructor invoked is automatically generated now, and there is no operator() to create confusion for the compiler at this version, but modern C++14 is supposed to offer clearer alternatives to avoid the "Most Vexing Parse", which g(S()) resembles.

So, I'd have to say that based on semantic rules, they both fail (not so badly though).

Comment: Omitting the const on the member functions was unintentional, though I'm not sure if it impacts the ill-formedness (or otherwise) of the examples.  I've added const just in case.

Comment: I've also changed the default constructed S to be a local variable in the second example, for clarity.

Comment: I'm not 100% myself, however, it only invokes the semantic issue that the function obviously operates as const, but isn't (or wasn't) declared const, and so would generate an error if an S were passed as a const & S or similar from which f() was called. I actually thought you were testing US out here ;)

Comment: Yes, and that doesn't happen in the examples, so why I don't think it effects the answer.

Comment: I'm also unclear as to your answer.  You say it fails based on semantic rules?  To which semantic rules are you refering?

Comment: If I take the definition from literature of a well-formed program, they don't limit the semantic question to only what is expressed in a particular example of code, but what such code would imply when future expansion is considered. The nature of {} vs () for initialization, for example, doesn't usually make a difference, until a compiler complains, but the "new" form for initialization opens a new semantic question that didn't exist in the older C++, which suggests that semantics aren't limited to enclosed examples, but more generally to what is written.

Comment: Consider this article http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/2006/0606/060511pb01/060511pb01.html on the subject. For a constexpr, const is not implied. Yet, in f() it clearly is written to BE a const function, and as such that was missing. That's a semantic conflict. In that article they offer void f(char); void f(double); f(3); The third is a semantic error, because it's not perfectly clear which f is intended.

Comment: When I ask "are the C++14 programs ill-formed?", I mean as per the definition of "ill-formed" specified in the C++14 standard.

Comment: What on earth is the fifth paragraph talking about. There are no possible MVPs in a `return` statement, and `S()` has nothing to do with `operator()`.

Comment: @M.M, the code no longer shows it, it was edited since that was posted, it wasn't the return, it was nested

Comment: @M.M (sorry, distracted) Here's the point. The original was g(S()). Look at S. Who writes an empty struct with 1 function? That makes no sense. It can't be finished, it has to grow. What will it be? Either it gets data, or it becomes a functor. C++11/14 is new, and I grew up with C++ since '90. Most books warn about what happens as code evolves, not just what's there right now. In Stroustrup's recent books all initializations use {}, not (), for that basic reason. If S gets an operator(), S() could be the functor call OR an S constructor. Which? S{} can't be confused.

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos, I skimmed the recent draft, but I find no section detailing semantic rules, they appear occasionally and cryptically scattered. Maybe you'll find something I can't. However, I don't think it will ever say, "constexpr functions should all be declared const". I don't think all semantic errors will be detailed, they refer to them as "diagnosable". Which tells me that when you can see a usage which generates compiler error, ask is that the intent? If S were passed as a const & S, then f() were called, is it intentional that it should be an error? I didn't think so.

Comment: @Andrew, BTW, at this point I can't find anything in the current version which could trigger the claim it's ill-formed. The only thing I see now, which I posted in comment above to M.M., is that S doesn't make sense except as example. In 20 years the only time I see a struct with no data members and one or two functions is a functor or, more recently, a lambda. That's not an error; it looks more like the beginning of something which must grow from here. As it is, obviously, f() is fine, and can't fire an error when an S is const, so it's clear of any potential of ambiguity.

Comment: @JVene no, `S()` *never* invokes `S::operator()`.  `return g(S());` is always identical to `return g(S{});` if `S` is any type name.