# static constexpr initialization chain within a class

Tags: c++, static, initialization, constexpr

I have a regular class, let's call it `Handler`, which performs some algorithm invoked on demand in runtime.
The algorithm reads an array (`m_arr`), its content is known at compile-time so I want to utilize `constexpr` to initialize it.

I don't want an aggregate initializer (it might look ugly), I'd like to use a function which initializes the array.
For the sake of elegance and encapsulation I want to keep them as `Handler`'s static members. The `m_arr` I'd like to qualify `constexpr` itself, because I want to init another array with another function basing on it (if I succeed with this one in the first place).

Currently I'm struggling with four propagating errors.
This is a draft of what I'm trying to achieve (with errors marked):

```
#include <array>
class Handler
{       
    static const int SIZE = 20;
    static constexpr std::array<int, SIZE> initArr();
    static constexpr std::array<int, SIZE> m_arr;  //C2737 'private: static std::array<int, SIZE> const Handler::m_arr': 'constexpr' object must be initialized

    //much other non-const stuff which this class handles...
};

constexpr std::array<int, Handler::SIZE> Handler::m_arr = Handler::initArr();  //C2131 expression did not evaluate to a constant

constexpr std::array<int, Handler::SIZE> Handler::initArr()
{
    std::array<int, SIZE> arr;  //C3250 'arr': declaration is not allowed in 'constexpr' function body
    arr[0] = int(2);    //C3249 illegal statement or sub-expression for 'constexpr' function
    arr[1] = int(7);    //C3249 illegal statement or sub-expression for 'constexpr' function
    arr[2] = int(4);    // -- || --
    //...
    return arr;
}
```

Apparently I'm doing something wrong here - or - I expect from the language something which it cannot provide (compiler - MSVC 2015/14.0).

Explanation of the reason of the errors (along with a closest working alternative) very very appreciated...

Comment: Did you include<array>?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  Show the definition of `LiteralType`.

Comment: @L.F. Here you have, I double-checked the error set is the same.

Comment: Shouldn't the `= initArray()` be part of the initial declaration?

Comment: Also, why do you think `static constexpr std::array<int, SIZE> m_arr{2, 7, 4};` is ugly?

Comment: @JVApen When I move `initArr()` to the array declaration (in the class body) I get C2131 too.

Comment: Does [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EVXV4loIuDQ7eIWU) reproduce your problem?

Comment: @L.F. Eventually I need to place literal type's constructor calls which is over 20 of them...

Comment: @L.F. C2131 and C2737 remain in your sample.

Comment: Yeah, that's what *reproduce* means.

Comment: @L.F. Yes, I know that, I wanted to be precise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, static functions in classes cannot be used to initialize `constexpr` static data members because the function definitions are not considered at the point of initialization.  You need to make it a free function and initialize the data member in the class body:

```
constexpr std::array<int, SIZE> init()
{
    // ...
}

struct C {
    static constexpr std::array<int, SIZE> arr = init();
};
```

Comment: So non-static member functions and global functions may serve as constexpr initialization measures (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803708/constexpr-member-functions-that-dont-use-this) but static methods no? I'm wondering the underlying reason of that...

Comment: @bloody Static member functions aren't considered to be defined until the end of the class definition, but the initializer for the `constexpr` static data member is processed in the class.  That's why you see a "call to undefined function" error if you make `init` a static function.

Comment: Assuming we have some loop-based complex initializing function (which cannot be replaced by an aggregate initializer anyway) it seems like a tangible limitation in the language (willing to contain all related stuff in the owning class). And such cases may be very common, I'm not a model but I myself do different runtime initializations (lookup tables, etc.) which otherwise might be processed as `constexpr` (and enclosed in a class for elegance). Wouldn't you agree with that?

Comment: @bloody Hmm ...  I get your point.  For now, just put the global function in a detail namespace :(