# Why operator() on non-constant expression is constant expression

Tags: c++

Consider following trivial example with a simple `Test` class with `operator()` which is `constexpr`. Even if `test` is not defined with `constexpr` keyword it may be used to yield size of an `std::array` during compile time. What is the reason behind such behaviour? Is this well defined in C++?

```
#include <array>

struct Test
{
  constexpr int operator()(int i) const { return i * 2; }
};


int main() {
  Test test{};
  std::array<int, test(10)> arr{};
}
```

On the other hand following does not compile:

```
struct Test
{
  int member;
  constexpr Test(int member): member(member) {}
  constexpr int operator()(int i) const { return i * member; }
};


int main() {
  /* constexpr */ Test test{10};
  std::array<int, test(10)> arr{};
}
```

In this case we need explicit `constexpr` in order to compile the code.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32803708

Comment: Well, in the first example, the operator() doesn't depend on any member of the struct. But in the second example, the function depend on the variable 'member'. And when you declare a static array, you need a const value for the size. Well, if your function wouldn't be constexpr and would depend on the member variable, it wouldn't be a const value

Comment: ` std::array<int, test(10)> arr{};` wll use the operator()(int i); and so that must be a constant expression which means `test` must be a constant expression to and thus you need a constexpr instance of test. (some slight syntax inprovements will also show intent a bit better on when you mean calling the operator or the constructor)  See : https://godbolt.org/z/KW5E5xhaM (always make your constructors with one argument explicit)

Comment: @PepijnKramer yeah, but why the former snippet does not require the `constexpr` keyword as we also need to have a `test` instance in order to invoke the method :)

Comment: Informally it's quite easy to understand.  You'are able to change `member` at runtime, hence your operator does not always produce a constexpr result, but template arg must be constexpr